# Trying to upgrade from ibatis version 2 to mybatis 3.3, got stuck with below snippet

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

```
<delete id="dProjects" parameterClass="java.util.Map">
        delete from pro_tbl
        where user_id = #uId#
        <dynamic prepend="AND">
            <iterate property="pIds" open="(" close=")" conjunction="OR">
                project_id = #pIds[]#
            </iterate>
        </dynamic>
</delete>
```

Trying to  upgrade from ibatis version 2 to mybatis 3.3. Since mybatis 3.3.0 doesn't support dynamic prepend anymore , need help with below snippet replacement ```

Comment: Check out [foreach](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach) tag. It would look something like this : `<foreach item="pId" collection="pIds" open="AND (" close=")" separator="OR">project_id = #{pId}</foreach>`.  `AND` can be included in `open`.